# System.Net.Mail.MailMessage Load from a String

Tags: c#, .net, email, mailmessage

I'm implementing an email sending logic. Here is what I'm planing to do.

Whenever system wants to send a email construct the MailMessage object (with all the details) and save that object in database (as string) instead of sending at the same time. From a background process those saved emails will be picked up and processed.

String will be taken from MailMessge.ToString() method.

Now my issue is, I can't see a way to get MailMessage object back from the saved string. I'm not sure whether this is supported by MailMessage class.

My second option is save the raw data in the queued table (to, subject, body etc) and construct the MailMessage object at the time of sending. I would prefer the first option due to it looks much neater.

If someone know how to achieve this, please let me know.

Thanks in advance,
Wijitha

Comment: `MailMessage.ToString()` is not going to transform the object into a string you can then use to recreate it later on.  The process that *does* do that (more or less) is called *Serialization* and there is no built in way to do that for a `MailMessage`.  Storing all the details of the message individually in your db table is actually much nicer, its trivial to read it back and construct an object by setting the appropriate properties and you have a nice, viewable, editable record of the message.

Comment: Thanks Alex, Yeah your right. I will go ahead with option 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. MailMessage.ToString() is not option.
2. In order to store any object in database or file Class need to be marked with Serializable but sadly in case of MailMessage it is not marked with Serializable attribute.
3. So you have to go for Second Option.

If you don't want to go for second option then Make Serializable version of MailMessage class that help you to store data in Database. Later you get that object back and convert to mailmessage and send email.

https://github.com/keyvan/Gopi/blob/master/Gopi/Gopi/SerializableMailMessage.cs

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It cleared out my issues. Will go with the Option 2. Using Chilkat API, I have achieved the option 1 before in a different project. I thought .Net also there is a way to do it.